# ExtDirectSpring Router URL?

Tags: spring, ext-direct

I'm trying to get [ExtDirectSpring](http://code.google.com/p/extdirectspring) to work but can't figure out what the URL to the Direct Router shall be.

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sonstiges/extdirect")
@Transactional
public class ExtDirectController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "")
  public String start() throws Exception {
    return "/sonstiges/extdirect";
  }

  @ExtDirectMethod(value = ExtDirectMethodType.STORE_READ)
  public List<String> loadAllMyStuff() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"one", "two"});
  }
}
```

In my JSP I add a provider like this:

```
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider({
                                 "type":"remoting",       // create a Ext.direct.RemotingProvider
                                 "url":"/fkr/app/controller/extjs/remoting/router", // url to connect to the Ext.Direct server-side router.    
                                 "actions":{              // each property within the actions object represents a Class
                                   "ExtDirectController":[
                                     // array of methods within each server side Class
                                     {
                                       "name":"loadAllMyStuff", // name of method
                                       "len":0
                                     },
                                     {
                                       "name":"myTestFunction", // name of method
                                       "len":0
                                     }
                                   ]
                                 },
                                 "namespace":"FKR"// namespace to create the Remoting Provider in
                               });
```

... and use the following store to populate a grid:

```
store: {
        model: 'Company',
        remoteSort: true,
        autoLoad: true,
        sorters: [
        {
            property: 'turnover',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            directFn: FKR.ExtDirectController.loadAllMyStuff
        }
  }
```

Loading the page, a request to http://localhost:8080/fkr/app/controller/extjs/remoting/router is send, but not to my loadAllMyStuff- function. My guess is that the URL to the direct router is wrong.

**What is the correct URL to the router?**

**EDIT:** I just figured out that the method *router* in *RouterController* expects the parameters *extAction* and *extMethod*, but with the given code the parameters *action* and *method* are sent. That seems to be odd ...